# Gibbs free energy density in superconductivity $g=f-\frac{1}{4\pi}B\cdot H$

Tags: thermodynamics, superconductivity

By definition, $G=F+PV$, where $G, F, P, V$ are Gibbs free energy, Helmholtz free energy, pressure and volume, respectively. How to derive the formula shown in the title ($g$ and $f$ are the density of Gibbs and Helmholtz free energy)?

I thought the energy density of the magnetic field is $\frac{1}{8\pi}H^2$ or $\frac{1}{8\pi}BH$, since H (magnetic field) = B (magnetic induction) in Gaussian units. Why the coefficient is $-\frac{1}{4\pi}$? And I am also not clear about the minus sign. Thanks.

source: Superconductivity JB Ketterson & SN Song

snapshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the coeff is in the *definition* of $\mathbf{B}$ vs. $\mathbf{H}$:  $$\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{H}+4\pi \mathbf{M},$$ and that $4\pi$ is there because it is not in the definition of the Coulomb force between magnetic poles when Gaussian units are employed. No matter what you do you will have a $4\pi$ thing *somewhere* in the Maxwell-Ampere-Lorentz-Heavisisde equations, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units.

The negative sign is there because of the diamagnetic nature of superconductivity. For an ideal diamagnet $\chi = -\frac{1}{4\pi}$ and the vectors of $M=\chi H$ and $H$ point in the opposite direction.

Comment: Thanks, but the place I'm not clear is why the Gibbs free energy $g=f-MB$ can be written into $g=f-\frac{1}{4\pi}B\cdot H$. 
Since it's talking about superconductivity, we can let $M=-H$, then we will get $g=f+\frac{1}{4\pi}B\cdot H$...